# How to check with VBA whether a xml node exists or not and if not print text into a combined string

Tags: xml, excel, xpath, vba

I'm modifying a piece of VBA code that requests XML data from the Google Geolocation API. Based on the given information (address) the Excel formula requests specific nodes from the API.

As example:

```vb
AdminAreaLvl3Node = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component
[type='administrative_area_level_3']/long_name")
```

The Google result XML file looks like this:

```xml
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
  <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>04028 Scauri LT, Italien</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Scauri</long_name>
   <short_name>Scauri</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Minturno</long_name>
   <short_name>Minturno</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Provincia di Latina</long_name>
   <short_name>LT</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
```

As a result the Excel formula should generate a string that contains the data

```vb
GetGeoData = LatitudeNode.Text & "," & LongitudeNode.Text & "," & 
AdminAreaLvl3Node.Text & "," & AdminAreaLvl2Node.Text & "," & 
AdminAreaLvl1Node.Text & "," & CountryNode.Text
```

Depending on the requested location some nodes are not included in the result. This generates an error (the formula cell keeps blank) although "lat" and "lon" as well as "country" data could be extracted.

To solve this issue I want to implement the following "if then" function, unfortunately the cell keeps still blank:

```vb
Set AdminAreaLvl3Node = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component
[type='administrative_area_level_3']/long_name")
        If Not AdminAreaLvl3Node Is Nothing Then AdminAreaLvl3Node = AdminAreaLvl3Node.Text 
        Else AdminAreaLvl3Node = "nicht vorhanden"
```

How can I get a string with all available defined nodes?

Comment: The cell is blank when the formula returns a blank value. If the formula raises an exception, the cell contains an error. Have you verified that your function returns correct value when called not from a sheet?

Comment: Yes, the function returns correct values when I do not include the "administrative_area_levels". When I only request "Country" and "lat" & "lon" there are no errors.

Comment: Have you verified that your function returns correct value when called *not* from a sheet?

Comment: sorry i am quite new to vba, how can I test that?

Comment: By creating a `sub` that calls it and executing it? By calling it from the immediate window?